# How to get Voltage gain from a cascaded transformers?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, feedback, gain, network

I am solving a problem from [Fundamentals of Electric Circuits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073380571) Chapter 13, Problem 65.

I know how to solve it using mesh analysis, on the other hand I am looking for a simpler method, so I am trying to use the idea used in [Miller approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect#Miller_approximation),so I can get rid of the 40 ohm (feedback)resistor, but I can't get the voltage gain for this port as It depends on the input current.

I stuck with  Vout/3 + 2 Vin = 25 Iin

[image: 2 port network with feedback]

My questions are:
How to get the voltage gain?
Are there any other methods to simplify the circuit?

Comment: This is an interesting circuit for learning how to analyze feedback circuits, but it's not one you're likely to run into in the real world, so there's not much point in trying to improve it. If you do, the feedback might be coming from a parasitic leakage path, not a designed-in device you get to choose to connect or disconnect.

Comment: Thanks for advise.
I just wanted to get rid of meshes.